# Converting void* to struct* and reading struct member values

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
int a;
} DATA;

int main()
{
  DATA *temp, *temp2;
  void *vtemp;
  temp = (DATA *)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
  temp->a = 5;
  vtemp = &temp;
  printf("set value : %d\n", temp->a);  

  // Some ops //

  temp2 = (DATA *)vtemp;
  printf("got value : %d\n", temp2->a);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm supposed to get "got value" as 5 but i'm getting a random number as follows (probably printing an address?):

```
set value : 5
got value : 7024656
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` is the address of the struct. When you write:

```
vtemp = &temp;
```

you set `vtemp` to be the address of `temp`, the variable. So, `&temp` is actually of type `DATA**`. When you cast `vtemp` to be of type `DATA*`, that is an error. Simple, `vtemp` is not of type `DATA*` and your cast does not change that.

I guess that you meant to assign `temp` to `vtemp`:

```
vtemp = temp;
```

Comment: thanks! I need to brush up with my pointers. Guess its the side effect of too much OOP programming :P

Answer (score 1):

Here temp is of type DATA

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
} DATA;
```

When `vtemp = &temp` means vtemp has the address of temp, which is of type `DATA*` and not `DATA`. So for you to dereference, you should declare vtemp as void**

change vtemp = &temp; to `vtemp = temp;` for your program to work or check the below code using `void**`

```
int main()
{
  DATA *temp, *temp2;
  void **vtemp;
  temp = (DATA *)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
  temp->a = 5;

  vtemp = (void *)&temp;

  printf("set value : %d\n", temp->a);  

  // Some ops //

  temp2 = *vtemp;
  printf("got value : %d\n", temp2->a);
  return 0;
}
```